# Any idea on how to implement the push-based messaging system using CoAP with Java?

Tags: java, notifications, push, coap

I am willing to use CoAP protocol for implementing a java push-based messaging system. Particularly in such a system, a client opens just once a connection with a server (resource) and the server pushes messages (‘non-confirmable’) with a specific rate (e.g., 10 messages per second).  However I did not find any existing solution to build the above system.

What I found is the pull-based messaging system. For such case, a client opens a connection with the server and after some time the client sends a GET request. Then, the server handles the request and pushes (as response) a single message to the client.

Hence, for each GET, I have a single message as response -- i.e., a two-way asynchronous interaction.

Does anybody have any idea on how to implement the push-based messaging system using CoAP? Does CoAP supports such a system?

The pull-based messaging system is implemented as follows

1. Server Part

   ```
       public class CoapServerPartAsync extends CoapServer {

                 private static final int COAP_PORT = 8891;
                 private static int incrementor = 1;
                 /*
                 * Application entry point.
                 */
                 public static void main(String[] args) {

                    try {

                    // create server
                    CoapServerPartAsync server = new CoapServerPartAsync();

                    // add endpoints on all IP addresses

                    server.addEndpoints();

                    server.start();

                    } catch (SocketException e) {

                         System.err.println("Failed to initialize server: " +   e.getMessage());
                    }
                 }

                /**
                 * Add endpoints listening on default CoAP port on all IP  addresses of all network interfaces.
                 *  
                 * @throws SocketException if network interfaces cannot be determined
                 */

                 private void addEndpoints() throws SocketException {


                     InetSocketAddress bindToAddress = new  InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", COAP_PORT);

                    addEndpoint(new CoapEndpoint(bindToAddress));

                    }

                   /*
                    * Constructor for a new Hello-World server. Here, the resources
                    * of the server are initialized.
                    */
                    public CoapServerPartAsync() throws SocketException {

                    // provide an instance of a Hello-World resource
                    add(new HelloWorldResource());
                    }

                  /*
                   * Definition of the Hello-World Resource
                  */

                   class HelloWorldResource extends CoapResource {

                         public HelloWorldResource() {

                         // set resource identifier
                         super("helloWorld");

                        // set display name
                        getAttributes().setTitle("Hello-World Resource");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange){

                    // respond to the request
                    System.out.println("Push [Hello World!"+(incrementor)+"]");
                     exchange.respond("Hello World!"+(incrementor));
                     incrementor++;

               }
          }
    }
   ```
2. Client Part

   ```
         public class CoapClientPartAsync {

                       // static boolean getResponse = false;

                       public static void main(String args[]) { 

                       CoapClient client = new CoapClient("coap://127.0.0.1:8891/helloWorld").useNONs();

                      while(true){
                         CoapObserveRelation relation = client.observe( 
            new CoapHandler() {

                    @Override public void onLoad(CoapResponse response){
                               String content = response.getResponseText();
                              System.out.println("NOTIFICATION: " + content);

                             }

                       @Override public void onError() {
                       System.err.println("OBSERVING FAILED (press enter to exit)");
                     }
                  });
                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }       
              }
          }
     }
   ```

Comment: `coap server` can not deal with push as `coap` is not like connection oriented, but you can observe a resource. You need a message queuing protocol. The best that suits the problem in situation where server push the messages is **MQTT**